# SQL C#, command(query) is executing twice

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

I have simple app to build sql query (for educational purposes).
I created textarea where user can write his command to sql, then program has to execute it or catch Sqlexeption. I know about safety etc. but its ok- user can delete everything :)

ok. here is the code:

query = text from textarea(its SQL command)

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query) || !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query))
{
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StudentDataBase"].ConnectionString;

    try
    { 
        using (SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {                
            try
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, SqlCon);
                SqlCon.Open();

                command.ExecuteScalar();

                int numOfRows = 0;

                SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataSet dset = new DataSet();
                adpt.Fill(dset);
                dt = dset.Tables[0];
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    numOfRows = dt.Rows.Count;
                    gridview_results.DataSource = dt;
                    gridview_results.DataBind();

                    Sql_error = "Done. Results: " + numOfRows + " rows.";
                    container_sql_error.Style.Add("background-color", "#b9ffcb");
                }
                else
                {
                    Sql_error = "0 rows to show.";
                }                           

                SqlCon.Close();
            }
             catch (SqlException ex)
            {
               Sql_error = "Error: " + ex.Message;
               container_sql_error.Style.Add("background-color", "#ff9600");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Sql_error = "Error... " + ex.Message;
        container_sql_error.Style.Add("background-color", "#ff9600");
    }
}
```

And now, when im trying:

`SELECT * FROM test` its OK. GridView showing data.

`slleeeccct * from testsste` its OK - showing an error.

`INSERT INTO test (col1) VALUES ('aaa')` its NOT OK- program throws error `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: cannot find table 0` BUT command was excecuted properly BUT TWICE.

Now i have a questions: why command is excecuting TWICE(2x same data in DB) and why is there an Error about `finding table 0` (is it about GridView maybe- cant fill GV with `insert into`)?

Comment: Well you're calling `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar` and then you're using the same command with a `SqlDataAdapter` and asking that adapter to fill a dataset... which it's going to do be executing the command again. Why are you calling `ExecuteScalar` at all?

Comment: Well, to execute command :), What should i call then?

Comment: @Kafus, I think Jon was implying that the call to `ExecuteScalar` is probably spurious and may be safely removed.  (as he stated, the `SqlDataAdapter` will execute the command itself)

Comment: On option is to have `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` and `SELECT` on the fronted as separate functions. Because how can you `SELECT` from an `INSERT` statement ? Not possible. So when the perform any of `C U D` you will need to run a separate `SELECT` and fill your datagrid.

Comment: Ok then, i removed ExcuteScalar and looks like it works. But still i have this error about table 0. Any solution or prompt?

Comment: This looks like you're building a method that will force you write code that is horribly vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It is **not** okay to use string concatenation to put data into SQL commands. You **must** include some mechanism for accepting parameters in your SQL. When you only deal with a `query` variable in the SqlCommand, and never look at the command's .Parameters collection, you're missing that mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all, you are executing the code twice**

**->** one time you are using ExecuteScalar and the other you are using the SQLAdapter to fill the dataset with returned results, you can just use it like the below:

```
1- dataset ds=new dataset();

2- adapter.fill(ds);

3- return ds;
```

and that's it :)

**Regarding** the insert query error, that's normal as well because the insert statement using [Execute Scalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) will Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

so when you use Insert statement, you are having an error because either

1- the command wasn't executed successfully and returned an error "Check if databsae has the inserted row you just typed"

2- dataset tables has no data, you can make an IF Statement check before you try to read from it like

```
"If(ds.tables.count>0) {do something}"
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what i need.